# What is the Idiom type for Xbox?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a UWP app created using Xamarin.Forms and I uploaded it on Microsoft Store, I enabled Microsoft to decide which platforms can I support, Xbox was automatically selected by Microsoft. I cant unfortunately test it since I dont have Xbox or any emulator available. But I am seeing that there are some downloads and Microsoft Developer Console shows the type as "Console"...
Now my question is on Xamarin.Forms doesnt have that idiom as Console, it is defined [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TargetIdiom/) as phone, tablet, desktop, tv, Unsupported... how to check for Xbox?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not built into Xamarin.Forms, so you will have to use Windows-specific API to recognize if the app is running on Xbox. You can implement a custom [Dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) that will have an interface which you will implement in UWP project. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) will tell you how to do it.

Then to check which type of device the app is actually running on you can check the value of:

```
Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily
```

This property contains a value depending on which type of hardware the app is currently open:

- `"Windows.Xbox"`
- `"Windows.Mobile"`
- `"Windows.Desktop"`
- `"Windows.Team"`
- `"Windows.IoT"`
- `"Windows.Holographic"`

Comment: good to know this. thank you. I think that we should request xamarin to include this in their v3.0 list :)

Comment: That is a very good idea! A kind of Console idiom. Or at least let Xbox One to be identified as TV?

Comment: I am not sure if that fits into TV category but I guess yes, it is possible.